# Modularised terraform code wants to destroy and recreate an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

This is a simplified example of my problem, for the sake of understanding.

My team used to manage an S3 bucket through the `module1`, which invoked `module2`, which contained the code of the bucket.

```
production_account/ --(invokes)--> module1/ --(invokes)--> module2/s3.tf
```

But then they decided to refactor the code, and directly invoke `module2`.

```
production_account/ --(invokes)--> module2/s3.tf
```

---

As a result, when I terraform plan now I get:

```
module.module1.module.module2.aws_s3_bucket.bucket will be destroyed { 
...
}

module.module2.aws_s3_bucket.bucket will be created { 
...
}
```

In short, terraform wants to recreate the s3 bucket. The problem with this is that all data will be lost.

Is there a way to import the existing bucket to the state **and** to manage it through module 2?

```
terraform import module.module1.module.module2.aws_s3_bucket.bucket
```

solves the first half of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use [terraform state mv](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/mv.html) not `import`.

```
terraform state mv module.module1.module2.aws_s3_bucket.bucket module.module2.aws_s3_bucket.bucket
```

Comment: Did it and I get `module.module2.aws_s3_bucket.bucket must be replaced`. "Replace" in Terraform's terminology means to destroy the existing object and create a new one to replace it. Doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you already `import` it?

Comment: If so, you'll need to use `terraform state rm module.module2.aws_s3_bucket.bucket` to forget it from that state location first.

Comment: I did not import it before executing the `state mv`, no. Now, I executed `terraform state rm module.module2.aws_s3_bucket.bucket` as you mentioned and it just wants to create a new bucket without destroying the old nowmore

Comment: If you do `terraform state list | grep "aws_s3_bucket.bucket"`, does it exist in your state anywhere? If so, you should be able to move it.

Comment: It does not exist! I used `terraform state rm`.

Comment: I executed the `state mv` command and it asked to replace. Then I executed `terraform rm` and now its gone.

Comment: Okay, but the resource should still be there, so as long as it is in neither the old state address or the new state address, you should be clear to import it into the new location and plan.

Comment: That is correct. Thank you @theherk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238512/discussion-between-dimitris-and-theherk).